# Why lodash's mapValues fails with _.first as callback?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, javascript-objects, lodash

I'm trying to convert

```
var stuff = { 1234: [{ name: "obj1" }], 3456: [{ name: "obj2" }] };
```

to

```
{ 1234: { name: "obj1" }, 3456: { name: "obj2" } }
```

(notice the singular arrays).

I figured out that:

```
_.mapValues(stuff, function(arr) { return _.first(arr); })
```

does the job, but what I don't understand why isn't the following enough?

```
_.mapValues(stuff, _.first)
```

It returns

```
{ 1234: [], 3456: [] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.mapValues` is passing more than just one argument to callback function. So your first example (to be equivalent) to second one should be:

```
_.mapValues(stuff, function() { return _.first.apply(this, arguments)})
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4F8Yg/) arguments passed to callback function are keyValue, keyName, stuff object.

Comment: Ah, so and the signature `_.first(array, [callback], [thisArg])` has some parameters filled in with totally wrong values, hence doing the wrong thing. Is there anything `fancy` (short, concise, out of the box) I can wrap `_.first` in to ignore anything but the first argument, like my callback with `arr` does: `_.mapValue(stuff, _.fancy(_.first))`?

Comment: @TWiStErRob: Sure: `_.fancy = function(c) { return function() { return c(arguments[0]); } };` ;)

Comment: That's not out of the box... I have to write it.

Comment: If you are using the underscore-contrib library alongside lo-dash/underscore, you can use _.unary : _.mapValue(stuff, _.unary(_.first)) 

- http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore-contrib/#unary

Comment: Beware that, as of lodash 3.0, _.first() only returns the first element of the array and that  _.take() must be used if you with to specify the number of elements from the beginning of the array to return. See https://lodash.com/docs#take and https://lodash.com/docs#first